# Fastest way to write & compile a C/C++ program in Windows

Tags: c++, c, ide, interactive

I'm usually using Visual Studio, but several things bother me when I just quickly want to test some code:

- it has a rather long startup time
- it always needs a project to execute/debug files
- program output gets printed to the console, but the window simply closes when I don't insert a `getchar()` or a breakpoint in the program and thus I'm not seeing it.

I'm looking for a program which is suitable for a really, really quick programming in Windows. Such as, copying some code from an SO question, running it and seeing its output.

I don't think that console programs or g++ under CygWin are a good solution, because there it takes ages to `cd` into the right dir to save the file, I'm not used to editors such as Vim, and typing in the compiler commandline myself has always annoyed me etc.

So I guess what I'm looking for is a very lightweight free C/C++ IDE which is preconfigured to work with a free compiler (bonus points if it is even shipped with it.)

What can you recommend which adresses at least two items from the list above?

Is there maybe even a program which can execute/interpret C or C++ in an interactive commandline (like Python)?

Comment: http://codepad.org and http://ideone.com/

Comment: <F5> runs your program in the debugger, <Ctrl><F5> runs it without debugger but in a window that waits for you to press enter after the program finished.

Comment: I have a junk console project called "foo" I keep for quick code testing. I can open the project, paste a code snippet into the foo.cpp, and compile/launch. It's fairly painless.

Comment: @WernerHenze: This is no longer true. With the latest Visual Studio/Windows, the console window will close without pausing regardless of whether it's run in the debugger.

Comment: With any IDE you're likely going to have some sort of 'project file(s)' which get created.  If you get VS up and running and create a single console app project, then all you'd need to do is paste in the code each time and compile.  Not really all that heavy weight at that point.  And as was said above, use F5 and your output goes to the output window.  I don't think you'd find other IDEs as being tons better than that.

Comment: if you really want minimal you might try MinGW, but if you want an IDE then I'm not sure you'll find codeblocks or anything else terribly different than just using VS tbh.

Comment: @dauphic: Are you talking about VS2010 or VS2011? In VS2010, when a program is launched with Ctrl-F5 "Start Without Debugging" the console stays open. I do this all the time.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: My MSVC10 closes with CTRL+F5.  Maybe it's a setting somewhere.  MSVC11 isn't out yet.

Comment: That's odd about the difference with Ctrl+F5. I just tested this and it works here. I'm using VS2010 but there is a Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview available.

Comment: I generally just run a linux machine next to my windows machine, or in a VM. Windows is just laughable for this.

Comment: Regarding the strange Ctrl+F5 non-deterministic behaviour: The MS feedback site says this is a bug and there is a workaround; see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552160/a-problem-in-visual-studio-2010-professional-start-without-deb

Comment: I began developing a desktop port of http://weegen.home.xs4all.nl/eelis/geordi/ that sits in your tray and uses Visual Studio's compiler. It's been on my to-do list for a while. I'll give you a link to it once I'm done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm looking for a program which is suitable for a really, really quick
>   programming in Windows. Such as, copying some code from an SO question
>   and executing it and seeing it's output.

For quick-and-dirty experimental coding, I really like [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/).  Not having to create a file is especially nice as it saves me from coming up with a suitable name and disk location.  Be aware that it uses g++ 4.1.2 [behind the scenes](http://codepad.org/about) so some of the latest C++11 features aren't supported.

Comment: Not the only useful answer, but I can only accept one, and codepad.org/ideone.com that Mooing Duck recommended struck me as most unexpected inventions.

Comment: Credit (and apologies) to @Mooing Duck.  I didn't even notice his comment when I posted this response.  I'll have to give ideone a shot.

Comment: It's also very common for answers to link to codepad/ideone to show proof of compilation.

Answer (score 5):

"really, really quick (and dirty, throw away?) programming "?

- Compiler : VC++ command line - you already have it.
- Editor:      Notepad or somesuch
- Compilation process: A .BAT file you write once
  and supply a parameter with the name of the single source file.
- Location: Set up some desktop shortcuts to a known directory for your
  test code.

Comment: Throw-away – yes. I'd still prefer a lightweight IDE over a separate editor and .BAT file. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 5):

Use [TCC : Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/)

1. start a command prompt
2. cd wherever
3. notepad main.c
4. write code in notepad. save
5. *back in the command prompt* type `tcc -run main.c`
6. notice errors, go back to 4

Note that with `-run` parameter you're invoking `tcc` like an interpreter

Answer (score 3):

Which compiler you use doesn’t really matter. I prefer G++ but `cl.exe` (from Visual Studio) works equally well.

In order to use the compiler quickly from the command line, either

1. include it into your PATH variable by [setting it in the system settings](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx), or
2. create a simple `.cmd` script which launches a console with the right paths included.

Visual Studio incidentally comes bundled with such a `.cmd` script which is linked in the Start Menu entry of Visual Studio. Personally, though, I prefer adjusting the PATH variable.

Then you can simply invoke the compiler from any directory in the command line. If you are too lazy to write the whole command line, create a script to do it for you. Or use Cygwin and (C)Make.

Two additional remarks:

1. Starting the project using the build configuration (Cntr+F5 (?)) leaves the console open after the program has run, without you having to include `getch()` calls or similar.
2. I highly recommend you learn an editor such as Emacs or Vim, unless you plan never to use any other platform than Windows, and even then. These editors are just tremendously powerful, and in some ways light-years beyond what the Visual Studio code editor offers.

   But if you really don’t have the time, use a decent text editor such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

[Open Watcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/) is easy to install and use, it's fast and it's the closest compiler to MSVC++, although it's noticeably behind in features (especially in C++).

I don't use its IDE at all as I got used to doing most of the stuff in the console, but it's there and the debugger is there too.

Compiling one-filers is easy.

Compiling C code:

```
wcl386.exe /we /wx /q sourcefile.c
```

Compiling C++ code:

```
wcl386.exe /xs /we /wx /q sourcefile.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

On my machine, I have a "empty" project called "Test".  When I want to test some random code on the internet, I simply put it into `main.cpp` in that project, and compile.

If you think MSVC takes too long to load, it should be possible to write a batch script that attempts to compile the project and puts the build log in a file.  Then you can simply alter the existing `main.cpp` with notepad, double click the batch file, then pop open the build log or run the executable.

[Edit] I made a batch file to compile the entire solution.  Turns out that requires loading visual studio.  However, the batch file can compile/run a single cpp file easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite IDE: http://www.codeblocks.org/

Here is a direct link to the download that includes the MinGW compiler: http://download2.berlios.de/codeblocks/codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe

You're not gonna find any (good) C/C++ interpreters.

Comment: I see codeblocks hasn't had an update in almost 1.5 years -- is that even still being maintained?  I tried looking around for some alternative windows IDEs awhile back but found the ones I saw weren't actively updated.

Comment: Actually, CB is updated constantly. Personally, I use the nightly builds. Yeah, the team is a bit slow at putting out "big official releases", but the IDE is heavily updated/maintained! Even so, the 10.05 release is plenty stable/adequate. Having a separately updated MinGW is more important than having a bleeding edge Code::Blocks.

Comment: ok, I was just going off the main download page - last version there was 1.5 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Once I used PSPad setting its "compiler" option for C++ files to a reasonable default (`cl.exe` in the correct directory, speed optimization, all warnings). Then it's just Ctrl+F9.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above compiler recommendations are good. For an editor, I really like [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)

I know you didn't ask...

Answer (score 0):

First off, your expectations are not reasonable. no program can guess what you want, over a range of input from the simplest to the most complex. If cd'ing into cygwin is too hard, and starting up visual studio is too time-consuming, you're pretty much toast. Sorry.

That said, you can edit code with notepad (which you can invoke from the command line as notepad foo.cpp). Notepad uses your mouse and the arrow keys on your pc so it's pretty intuitive.

you can use visual studio tools from the command line, without having to fiddle with project files.

Visual studio comes with a tool called nmake, the most basic usage of which is similar to linux make. If you have very simple input, nmake's default rules may be good enough to produce an executable. If not, you may be able to construct a makefile that will take any single simple file, say foo.cpp, and compile and link it to an executable called foo.exe. You'll still have to learn to use nmake, which some people think is easy, and others think is fiendishly difficult. Try nmake foo.cpp and see if the result is what you want.